# filter password with php

Tags: php

What's the best way to filter a password with php built in filters (SANITIZE and VALIDATE).
How can I verify the password length?

With a number should be easy with:

```
"options" => array(
   'min_range' => 6,
   'max_range' => 25
)
```

So in the above  example how can  check the length?

```
array(
   "filter" => SANITIZE_STRING,
   ->check length!?!
)
```

Comment: Limiting the maximum password length is not useful.

Comment: Why do you need to sanitize it? It should pose no threat as long as you are properly encrypting it before inserting into database, and when comparing it should pose no threat as well as it should be encrypted before comparing. If you sanitize the password you render it useless. Imagine me making a password `h^H25>'U` and you sanitized it, you ended up changing my strong password.

Comment: How come? What about buffer overflow?

Comment: @FCC-PT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: So you saying that I should hashing it before filtering?

Comment: @FCC-PT Show it to me :) Buffer overflows are covered by other parts of the engine, you should take care about safe passwords ;) Anyway, if you really concern such problems, you can at least set a high limit, like `PHP_INT_MAX`. In fact you don't need to filter it at all. Maybe you want to provide a "minimum secure password", but thats just convenience for your users. After hashing the password cannot do any harm anymore (except "being to easy" ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` to do it:

```
$password = "My Great Password";
filter_var($password, 
  FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
  array( "options"=> array( "regexp" => "/.{6,25}/"))
);
```

Comment: So after this I will have to hash it before compare or even submit to db... of course this expects me to use one way encriptyon right?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, why you want to do it with the builtin-filter

```
if (strlen($password) < $options['min_range'])) {
  // Password too short
}
```

Now just hash it (with a secure hash algorithm) and push it in the database. There is no further step required for you. However, you maybe want to warn your user, if they try to set a "easy password", like a regular word, a sequence, or something like that. Also I recommend to *not* limit the maximum length, because why do you want to do this?